# PubSub the connection was interrupted while the page was loadibng error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a PubSub subscribed here

```
ul.questions_list
 -if(@questions.empty?)
    |no questions available
 -else
   -@questions.each do|question|
     li 
       =link_to"#{ question.title } ", question_path(question)      

p= link_to 'Ask question', new_question_path
= subscribe_to '/questions'
```

then goes coffee(in this case console.log  gives right data)

```
$ ->
  PrivatePub.subscribe '/questions', (data, channel) ->
    question = $.parseJSON(data['question'])
    console.log(question.title)
    $('.questions_list').append("<li><a href='/questions/#{question.id}'>#{question.title}</a></li>");
```

And controller

```
  def create
    @question = Question.new(question_params)
    @question.user = current_user
    if @question.save
      PrivatePub.publish_to '/questions', question: @question.to_json
      redirect_to @question, notice: 'Your question successfully created.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

I recieve such error

```
The connection to ws://localhost:9292/faye was interruped while the page was loading.
...et;t.exports={create:function(t){return **new** n(t)}}}).call(e.function(){return th...)
```

I do not understand where Im doing wrong. Would be very grateful for any help

Answer (score 0):

I dropped db and now everything is ok. Can anybody explain what happened?